# Crystal Reports: expressions in table joining

Tags: crystal-reports

Is it possible to join tables in Crystal Records by using not simple and usual field A = field B but something more complex like:

```
select * from table1 inner join table2
on table1.A=2*table2.B
```

or

```
select * from table1 inner join table2
on ASCII(table1.A)=ASCII(table2.B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a single Command instead of tables in the Database Expert.  You will be able to use more-complex SQL.